# How I can pass data to Worker Service in ( .Net core 6) from Web API .Net core 5

Tags: api, service, service-worker, pass-data

I am writing a worker service in Net core 6 and I want to call the worker service from API and pass sone data to worker service.

My Worker service code is as below:

``

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseWindowsService(options =>
     {
         options.ServiceName = "TestWindowService";
     })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<ServiceWorker>();
        services.AddTransient<ITestService, TestService>();
        services.AddTransient<IDatabaseClientService, DatabaseClientService>();
    })
   .Build();
   
   await host.RunAsync();
```

``

I am calling Worker service from API and want to pass some data to Worker Service:

I tried this code from API but it is not working:

``

```
 ServiceController service = new ServiceController();
            service.MachineName = ".";
            service.ServiceName = this.WindowServiceName;

            if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                service.Start(new string[] { "Testargs" });
```

``
How can I pass data from API to worker service? I tried the above code, but it is not working.
Once the service is running then I want to pass data to it again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a message queue, such as [Azure Storage Queues](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/queues/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) / [Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) / [Google Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks). On-premise solutions also exist, such as [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/).

The idea is that the API serializes a message and sends it to the message queue before returning an HTTP response. The background service reads from that queue and handles those messages. I have more information about this pattern in my blog posts on [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html) and [queues in particular](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-2-durable-queues.html).